# AngularJS injector issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to call a WebAPI from AngularJS. It is a simple GET request, and I have enabled CORS on the server.

I am getting the **$injector:unpr Unknown Provider** error.

I have an angular module called **raterModule.js**:

```
var raterModule = angular.module('rater', []);
```

a service called **corsService.js** that uses the snippet from enable-cors.org:

```
raterModule.factory("corsService",
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    }
    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest. XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {            
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    }
    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    else {            
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

)

and finally a controller called **menuController.js**:

```
raterModule.controller("menuCtrl",["$scope","$http","corsService",
    function menuCtrl($scope, $http, corsService) {
        var xhr = corsService.createCORSRequest('GET', 'http://localhost:50942/api/menu/items');
        if (!xhr) {
            throw new Error('CORS not supported');
        }
        // Getting menu items
        $http.get(xhr)
                    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.menu = data;
                    })
                    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("error getting menu items");
                    });
    }
]);
```

These are all included at the bottom of an HTML index page. What I was hoping to happen would be that *corsService* is injected into *menuCtrl*, and then *menuCtrl* is added to the *raterModule*.

The menuCtrl would use corsService to create a request which is then sent to the WebAPI, avoiding the same-origin policy problem.

I'm sure it is something simple but in my ignorance I cannot see it.

Comment: Can you paste your HTML code and also the full error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an error because Angular expect that you gonna inject providers named `method` and `url` in your `createCORSRequest`, not function parameters.

So, you can review your `corsService` in following way:

```
raterModule.factory(`corsService`, function() {
    var service = {};

    service.createCORSRequest = fucntion(method, url) {
    // your logic here
    };

   return service;
})
```